# Change Background Color of AppCompat Action Bar

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am in a fragment and I want to change the actionbar color and view background color when the user clicks on a button.  The code I currently have below causes the action bar to go gray no matter what color the user chooses.

```
private void changeColor( int colorId ) {
    ActionBar actionBar =  ((ActionBarActivity )getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( colorId ) );
    this.getView().setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor( colorId ) );
}
```

I have the actionbar themed to be blue in my styles.xml not sure if that has any effect.  If you have any suggestion please let me know.

Thanks,
Nathan

Solution:
Had to change:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( colorId ) );
```

To:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( getResources().getColor( colorId ) ) );
```

Comment: What if you remove your blue color from styles.xml?

Comment: Same problem, I am also noticing that when I try to set the background color of a linear layout on one of my listview rows I get get the same gray color.           holder.titleLayout.setBackgroundColor( item.getColorCode() );

Comment: @Nath5, refrain from answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 8):

If i understand your question correctly that you want to change the color base on user intervention, try this instead.

```
public void setActionBarColor(int parsedColor){
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(parsedColor));
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}
```

using this in a fragment

```
// check if instance of activity is MyActivity just an example
MyActivity mA = ((MyActivity)getActivity());
mA.setActionBarColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA2C13E"));
```

hope it helps :)

PS: im using `ActionBarActivity`